# RxJs: Execute a long running function immediately after returning, giving the caller an Observable for updates

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-marbles

I have a function that could be considered long running (actually, it's multi-step where each step could be waiting for an external event like a response from a HTTP call).

There's an invoker function to this which should return an observable that returns the updates to the original function. The original function MUST run whether or not the returned observable is subscribed to. Basically, it needs to return a hot observable.

I have tried the following approach but, cannot get it to work:

```js
function longRunningOperation(): Observable<number> {
  const updates$ = new Subject<number>();
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log('starting updates...');
    updates$.next(1);
    updates$.next(2);
    updates$.next(3);
    updates$.complete();
  });
  return updates$;
}
```

If I do a marble test on the above, I see that the actual events generated being empty (though the function does execute).

```js
  it('should return and start executing', () => {
    const updates$ = longRunningOperation();
    const marbles = '(abc|)';
    const events = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

    new TestScheduler((actual, expected) =>
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected)
    ).run(({ expectObservable }) => {
      expectObservable(updates$).toBe(marbles, events);
      console.log('Test Scheduler subscribed');
    });
  });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Link to demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-in-angular-upoavr?file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts

Comment: Your test scheduler looks like it's subscribing after your promise resolves (why are you mixing async libraries anyway?) Since your observable is hot, the late subscriber is just given a complete emission.

Comment: @MrkSef your explanation makes sense. However, if you look at the demo (link added to the question), the sequence of events printed indicate that the Test Scheduler subscribes before updates starts emitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can test this scenario with marbles, at least in a simple way.

Marbles are a **synchronous mechanism**, while `Promise`s are always **asynchronous**.

Therefore, when your test executes the `run` method of `TestScheduler` it does it synchronously. The `Promise` though will be resolved later by the JS engine, so only later the `update$` Subject will emit its values.

This is the reason why the test says that it gets 0 notifications from `update$` rather than the 4 it expects. The notifications from `update$` will come after the assertion has been evaluated.

If you want to test this scenario without marbles, you can do something like this

```
describe('Testing tests', () => {
  it('should return and start executing', (done) => {
    const updates$ = longRunningOperation();
    const expected = [1, 2, 3]
    const actual = []

    updates$.subscribe({
      next: d => {
        actual.push(d)
      },
      complete: () => {
        // expected equal to actual
        expect(actual.length).toEqual(expected.length)
        actual.forEach((v, i) => expect(v).toEqual(expected[i]))
        done()
      }
    })

  });
});
```

as can be seen in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-in-angular-ss7e1m?file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts).

**UPDATE**

Maybe there is a way to test your scenario with marbles, but this requires a change in the structure of your function.

Marble tests, for what is my experience, define some sort of source streams, apply to such streams some kind of transformations and then compare the results of the transformation with the expected stream values.

In this case the source stream can be a simple Observable that notifies just once. This notification than triggers the execution of the *long running function* which itself causes `update$` to notify.

So, we can change slightly the `longRunningOperation` function like this

```
function longRunningOperation_(start$: Observable<any>): Observable<number> {
  const updates$ = new Subject<number>();
  // as soon as start$ notifies, the long running function is executed
  start$.pipe(
    tap(() => {
      console.log('starting updates...');
      updates$.next(1);
      updates$.next(2);
      updates$.next(3);
      updates$.complete();
    })
  )
    .subscribe();

  return updates$;
}
```

Once you have done so, you have created the space for a source stream (in this case represented by the Observable passed to the `longRunningOperation_` function as parameter) and so the test can be run like this

```
it('should return and start executing', () => {
    new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
      console.log('Comparing...');
      console.log('actual:', actual);
      console.log('expected:', expected);
      return expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    }).run(({ hot, expectObservable }) => {
      const start = hot('0');
      const marbles = '(abc|)';
      const events = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

      const updates$ = longRunningOperation_(start);
      expectObservable(updates$).toBe(marbles, events);
      console.log('Sheduler subscribed');
    });
  });
```

Look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-in-angular-ralo5h?file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts) for the full example.

Comment: I have added a second part to the answer where I show a possible way to use marbles also in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a little mystified by the way TestScheduler works (especially since you mentioned that it will execute synchronously). I always assumed that `expectObservable`  would subscribe to the given observable and track the emitted events. I thought it would create a fake-async zone.

Comment: Consider that [Observables are just specialized functions](https://benlesh.com/posts/learning-observable-by-building-observable/). Javascript functions are synchronous, unless something makes them async. Therefore Observable are by default synchronous unless there is something that makes them async. Marbles do not have anything async. To be honest, in my opinion TestScheduler does a bit of black magic, but still synchronously.